# Providing additional View assemblies to MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

In a Xamarin Forms app, I want to provide another View assembly (than default one) where MvvmCross can look for Views.

After following [MvvmCross Wiki](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customizing-using-App-and-Setup#providing-additional-view-and-viewmodel-assemblies), in UWP's Setup class, I `override GetViewAssemblies()` to add additional assemblies:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewAssemblies()
    {
        var viewAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        viewAssemblies.AddRange(base.GetViewAssemblies());
        viewAssemblies.Add(typeof(MovementPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        return viewAssemblies;
    }
```

But app complains, it isn't able to find the View:

```
mvx:Diagnostic: 10.46 Setup: Secondary end
mvx:Diagnostic: 10.51 Showing ViewModel MovementViewModel
Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in MvvmCross.Core.dll
mvx:Diagnostic: 10.82 Page not found for MovementPage
mvx:Error: 10.84 Skipping request for MovementViewModel
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in MovementTimer.UWP.exe
```

When this Page is present in default assembly (assembly containing ViewModels, App.cs), Page is displayed.

What can be done here?

Comment: I'm doing so as to put Views & Business Logic in separate assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `InitializeViewLookup()` works, but it's tedious :(

```
protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
{
    var viewsLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
    {
        [typeof(MovementViewModel)] = typeof(MovementPage)
    };

    var container = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
    container.AddAll(viewsLookup);
}
```